# Are my bound-computations (using Sobolev embeddings) correct?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification, sobolev-spaces

Working on a connected, bounded subset $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ with a smooth boundary, the following is true:
for $(u, v, w) \in W^{1,2}(\Omega)\times W^{1,6}(\Omega) \times W^{1,2}(\Omega)$, the following integrals are bounded:

$$
        (a) \int_\Omega v^2 \times \nabla u\cdot\nabla w\\
        (b) \int_\Omega v^3 \times w\\
        (c) \int_\Omega v^4, \quad \int_\Omega v^5\\
        (d) \int_\Omega v^2 \times |\nabla u|^2\\
        (e) \int_\Omega |\nabla u| \times v^2 \times |\nabla w|^2\\
$$

My solution: I use the following Sobolev embeddings:
$$
        W^{1,6}(\Omega) \subset C_B(\Omega) = \{v \in C^0(\Omega) : v \in L^\infty(\Omega)\}\\
        L^p(\Omega) \subset L^q(\Omega) \qquad \forall 1 \leq q < p \leq \infty
$$

$$
(a) \leq \|v\|_{0,\infty}^2\int_\Omega\nabla u \cdot \nabla w \leq \|v\|_{0,\infty}^2\|u\|_{1,2}\|w\|_{1, 2}\\
(b) \leq \|v\|_{0,6}^3\|w\|_{1, 2}\\
(c) \leq \|v\|_{0,3/2}, \|v\|_{0,6/5}\\
(d) \leq \|v\|_{0,\infty}^2 \|u\|_{1,2}^2\\
(e) ~\text{is possibly unbounded}
$$

Thanks very much!